# Bizzarre behaviour of "echo !!" under interactive Bash. Is this a feature?

Tags: bash

I wanted to test something in shell and I've typed `echo "!!"` instead of typical `echo "foo"`.

I didn't get the `!!` for output. Instead, (and very unexpectedly!) it produced the output of my previous command issued for Bash.

I tried to google the phrases `bash !!` (and permutations like `bash +"!!"`), but I couldn't find any reference for this feature.

Can someone tell me something about the exclamation marks' stuff and Bash? At least how to find extra info?

I use Bash 4.2.45 on Linux Mint 16 64 bit.

Comment: This did not just produce the output from the previous command (out of some cache), it actually **runs** the previous command.

Comment: @Zelda No, it doesn't execute the last command, it just inserts it. `!!` alone on a line will execute the last command, while `echo "!!"` will just echo the last command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man bash`, section `HISTORY EXPANSION`:

> #### Event Designators
>
> An event designator is a reference to a command line entry in the history list.  Unless the reference is absolute, events are relative to the current
>          position in the history list.
>
> [...]
>
> **!!** - Refer to the previous command.  This is a synonym for `!-1'

You can turn history expansion off with `set +H` if you don't like it. I generally prefer to use readline to do history lookups instead.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put the exclamation marks between single quotes.

```
$ echo '!!'
!!
$
```